# Laravel 7 - Timestamp field becomes ISODate

Tags: laravel

I have got a problem. When updating the model twice, the updatedAt field becomes from timestamp to ISODate. So after second loop updatedAt is changed to ISODate. Is there any explanation why does it work like this.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    $user = User::find('10');
    $user->mode = rand(1, 10);
    $user->save();
}

"updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-28T15:46:16.773Z"),
"createdAt" : 1611844860
```

Here is the User Model Class:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';

protected $casts = [
    'createdAt' => 'timestamp',
    'updatedAt' => 'timestamp',
];

public function setCreatedAtAttribute()
{
     $this->attributes['createdAt'] = time();
}

public function setUpdatedAtAttribute()
{
    $this->attributes['updatedAt'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Why are you overriding all the normal behaviors - the name of the field, mutators, casts? `created_at`/`updated_at` work out-of-the-box in a default install.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not to use mutators, use protected $dateFormat & $dates instead of $casts nor mutators , e.g

```
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
protected $dates = ['createdAt', 'updatedAt'];
```